# Open a new Qt window with a slot

Tags: c++, qt

In my Qt Program, there is a menu bar where one of the menu options is Settings. When the user click on the Settings window, it should open a Settings window. The settings window gets opened with a `openSettingsWindow()` function. This is how I made the Settings menu in the main window:

```
QMenu settingsMenu("&Settings");
QAction *settings = toolsMenu.addAction("&Settings");
Window::connect(settings,&QAction::triggered,&mainWindow,[&mainWindow](){
    openSettingsWindow();
});
menuBar.addMenu(&toolsMenu);
```

`mainWindow` is the main window and `Window` is the class used to create windows which inherits from `QWidget`. Its constructor takes two arguments: the title of the window and the icon of the window. This is the `openSettingsWindow()` function:

```
void openSettingsWindow(){
    Window settingsWindow("Settings","icon.png");
    settingsWindow.show();
}
```

The problem is that when I click ont he Settings option in the Settings menu, the Settings window opens as it should, but it closes directly after less than a second. What should I do to keep the Settings window opened?

Comment: ***but it closes directly after less than a second.*** Window goes out of scope when `openSettingsWindow()` ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a reference to that `Window` and keep it until you're no longer using it.

```
Window *openSettingsWindow() {
    Window *settingsWindow = new Window("Settings, "icon.png");
    settingsWindow.show();
    return settingsWindow;
}

QMenu settingsMenu("&Settings");
QAction *settings = toolsMenu.addAction("&Settings");
Window *settingsWindow = null;
Window::connect(settings,&QAction::triggered,&mainWindow,[&mainWindow, &settingsWindow](){
    settingsWindow = openSettingsWindow();
});
menuBar.addMenu(&toolsMenu);
```

You might want to find a better way of storing the `settingsWindow` pointer in the main function if you're going to have many possible open windows but this will work.

Remember to call `delete()` on that pointer when you're done with the settings window (likely on the window close event)

Comment: After the edit, you are leaking `Window` objects, `settingsWindow` never gets destroyed.

Comment: The OP is free to handle the returned Window pointer however they wish to, store it somewhere where they can free it when it is time. I don't have enough code from them to tell when is a good time to do so.

Comment: I tried that and got the error `error: C3493: 'settingsWindow' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified`.

Comment: My bad, forgot to capture `settingsWindow` in that lambda, should work now

Comment: you can use [`Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) to make Qt delete the `Window` object automatically for you when it is closed, no need to return the pointer from the `openSettingsWindow`.

Answer (score 2):

The local variable `settingsWindow` gets destructed when your function `openSettingsWindow` goes out of scope, you need to keep the object valid as long as you want to show your `settingsWindow`.

one solution would be to allocate the `Window` object on the heap, and use the [`Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) to make Qt delete the `Window` object for you when it is closed, here is how your `openSettingsWindow` would look like:

```
void openSettingsWindow(){
    Window* settingsWindow = new Window("Settings","icon.png");
    settingsWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    settingsWindow->show();
}
```